# Error 1064 (42000) error sql syntax

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, script, cuenta-usuario

Tengo la siguiente linea de código en un script bash.

```
echo password | sudo -S su -l otrouser -c 'mysql  -e "GRANT ALL ON wordpress.* to 'usuario'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'userpass';"'
```

Quiero ejecutar la sentencia `mysql` como otro usuario.
Si ejecuto la sentencia directamente en la consola mysql la ejecuta sin problemas.
No se si puede ser un problema de comillas simple, dobles o demasiados comandos anidados.

Gracias.-

Comment: Tiene toda la pinta de ser un problema con las comillas precisamente.No tengo muy fresco el linux, intenta escapar las comillas simples con \ : `echo password | sudo -S su -l otrouser -c 'mysql  -e "GRANT ALL ON wordpress.* to \'usuario\'@\'localhost\' IDENTIFIED BY \'userpass\';"'`

Comment: igual no harua un bash para crear un usuario, es muy riesgoso, te recomiendo entrar a tu consola mysql y ejecuta el comando, si creas el bash le vas a mostrar la clave root me parece muuuy inseguro

Answer (score 2):

Mi consejo es que crees el script usando sudo de manera normal (sin lo de `echo`) y luego le des permisos de `sudo` sin contraseña:

Editas `/etc/sudoers` con el comando `visudo` y das a tu usuario el permiso `NOPASSWD` a tu script:

```
<nombre_de_usuario> ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /opt/mi-script.sh
```

De esa manera, si haces "sudo" en ese script, tendrás acceso inmediato al usuario pedido sin necesidad de contraseña.

Comment: Estupenda respuesta. Y mucho mas seguro que lo que intentaba el OP,